# Splitting 0-10V Analog signal from 1 AO to two different set of Ventilators to regulate speed?

Tags: analog, signal, plc, regulations, load-regulation

Is it possible to take 0-10V signal from analog output and split it in parallel to two different Analog inputs ..to regulate speed of two different sets of ventilators? Or do i need some special devices like ..signal conditioners?

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure that your analog output can drive more analog inputs. For example, each analog input has 10k ohm input impedance, then the current is 1mA. If you connect two devices, the analog output shall be capable to deliver more than 2mA.

Answer (score 0):

I will  depend on the input impedance of the inputs and the output impedance of the output. If the combined inputs have a low input impedance compared to the output, then you will need some type of buffering. Say an opamp as unity-gail followe or a simple emitter follower.